# How do you check for a url param in a if statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to check for a url param in an if statement, but I don't know the proper syntax or if this is even possible.

so far I got

```
<% if param(order: :top) %>
<% elsif param(order: :top && live: :true) %>
```

both of which I know are wrong.

The url params I'm trying to check for are:

www.url.com/?live=true&order=top

or

www.url.com/?order=top

index.html.erb

```
<% current_user.following_channels.each do |c| %>
<% if param(order: :top) %>
<% c.discussions.where('created_at > ?', 1.days.ago).each do |discussion| %>
<% elsif param(order: :top && live: :true) %>
<% c.discussions.where('live = ?', true).each do |discussion| %>
<% end %>
    Some more code...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense to me, anyway:

```rb
if params[:order] == 'top'
  if params[:live] == 'true'
    c.discussions.where(live: true).each do |discussion|
    .
    .
    .
    end
  else
    c.discussions.where('created_at > ?', 1.days.ago).each do |discussion|
    .
    .
    .
    end
  end
end
```

Also, as you learn Rails you should move all that logic to the controller and model.

EDIT: Moving logic to controller (**untested code**, it may fail):

```rb
def index
  @channels = current_user.following_channels.includes(:discussions)
  @channels = @channels.where('discussions.created_at > ?', 1.days.ago) if params[:order] == 'top'
  @channels = @channels.where(discussions: {live: true}) if params[:live] == 'true'
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```rb
<% @channels.each do |channel| %>
  <div class="channel-container">
    <h2><%= channel.name %></h2>

    <ul>
    <% channel.discussions.each |discussion| %>
      <li><%= discussion.text %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That way, the view knows nothing about how to get data, it just presents it to user.

You still can move logic from controller to the models, but get comfortable with all of this first.

Comment: Can I ask why it's important to have code in the controller & model instead of the view?

Comment: It's all about the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Views shouldn't contain any bussiness logic, just display data.

Comment: Or better yet, service objects. Skinny logic-free views; skinny models, skinny controllers, and skinny everything else, too.

Comment: How would you move something like this to a controller? How do I display the data in a collection without putting an each loop in the view?

Answer (score 0):

```
params["live"].nil? #this will return false if there is no url parameter called "live"

params["live"].blank? # this will return false if url parameter live is blank
```

So on, for the other parameters. As CAmador has said, you need to move your codes mostly to controller(in this case of dealing with params, the code should go to controller).